# Error creating virtual environment using venv

Tags: ubuntu, centos, python, python3, virtualenv

I am trying to set up a Python development environment on Centos7 , I am relatively new to both Linux and Python. I am following this guide to setup the environment but I am getting an error when I have to setup virtual environment.
Using this guide:

```
https://www.metachris.com/2016/03/how-to-install-qt56-pyqt5-virtualenv-python3/
```

but when I run this to create virtualenv for PyQr5, I get this error:

```
python3 -m venv ~/.venv/qtproject
Error: Command '['/root/.venv/qtproject/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I can see it created the directory structure, but I don't see any activate file to get the env activated.

```
[root@cent7 qtproject]# ls
bin  include  lib  lib64  pyvenv.cfg
```

when I try to activate the env, it just seems to fail as there is no activate file or folder.

```
[root@cent7 bin]# source activate
bash: activate: No such file or directory
```